# update data from a dictionary in pandas using update

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
from account import Account
import pandas

print("welcome to Ot's Bank App.\n")

new_account = Account()

print(new_account.account_details())


# 2. Store details in a csv file.


def csv_data_operations():
    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(new_account.account_details(), orient="index")
    try:
        user_data = pandas.read_csv("accounts.csv")
        print(user_data)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df.to_csv("accounts.csv", index=False)
    finally:
        df.update(df)


csv_data_operations()
```

I tried to create a dataframe and use exceptions to create a csv where file not found error occurs, and to update the records from the same dataframe where csv exists.

Comment: maybe you are looking for [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: i get this when i tried pd.concat .

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you want to do.  I'm just guessing based on your `try..except`.  You need to edit your question and add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or no one can help you.

Comment: Sorry i may not be expressing my problem the right way, i'm a newbie. So what i have been trying to achieve so far is to get the code to add a new row of records to my accounts csv. Im creating a demo bank app with an account class, it accepts inputs from user on cli and the account details method creates a dictionary and returns it. so each time the program runs, for now, a new account with all the details would be populated in the dictionary. Then i used pandas with the try block to add these records to csv or create a new one if csv it doesn't exist.

Comment: I would urge you to put this in the question, instead of a comment, with a working code example.  That said, from your description it seems my original suggestion is what you need: you want to update (accumulate new records), and concat is the recommended way.  However, this isn't scalable once you have more accounts.  So you probably need a better than "one entry at a time" way to add new accounts.

Answer (score 0):

As @suvayu suggested, `pd.concat()` should do it for you. You can change your function like below:

```
def csv_data_operations():
    df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(new_account.account_details(), orient="index")
    try:
        user_data = pandas.read_csv("accounts.csv")
        print(user_data)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df.to_csv("accounts.csv", index=False)
    finally:
        df = pd.concat([df, user_data], axis=1)
```